# Printing special numbers within a range not working

Tags: java

Need to use these three methods to print all the Special numbers between `s` and `l`. However my program just prints something else instead. Can't find what I did wrong. Any help would be appreciated :)

I've tried calling `fact` with or without 'this'.

```
static int fact(int num)
{   
    int fac = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=num; i++)
    {
        fac = fac*i;
    }
    return(fac);
}


static void swag(int s, int l)
{   
    int sum = 0;
    int d,temp, fax, i;
    for(i=s;i<=l;i++)
    {
        temp = i;
        while(temp>0)
        {
            d=temp%10;
            fax = fact(d);
            sum += fax;
            temp/=10;
        }
     if(sum==i)
     System.out.println(i+" is special");
    }
}
static void Print()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    swag(input.nextInt(),input.nextInt());
}
```

}

for 1-1000, expected to be:

```
1 is special
2 is special
145 is special
```

what I'm getting:

```
1 is special
```

Note: for 2-1000 it prints `2 is special` and from 3-1000 doesn't print anything

Comment: what do you see when you step through this in a debugger?

Comment: Following @ControlAltDel's point: watch what happens with `sum`.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm a 10th grade computer science student, not too sure what a debugger is...

Comment: @Andreas: the issue here has *nothing* to do with recursion.

Comment: Yo @Andreas temp%10 is 5 in that case, not 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not resetting the value of `sum` to 0 in the loop.

```
static void swag(int s, int l)
{   int sum = 0;int d,temp, fax, i;
    for(i=s;i<=l;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        temp = i;
        while(temp>0)
        {
            d=temp%10;
            fax = fact(d);
            sum += fax;
            temp/=10;
        }
     if(sum==i)
        System.out.println(i+" is special");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! Works perfectly now. Thanks for the succinct answer instead of the other condescending ones lol.

Comment: Chill, most people mean well. Do learn how to use a debugger in your IDE when possible, it can be a life saver. Cheers.